# Pass option value from HTML select to url

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a Bootstrap modal that allows the user to select a flight they want to complete and is then redirected to a form. I'm not sure however how I can pass or POST the option value (`flight_id`) that they select to the form so that it appears something like `/formpostflight.php?flight_id=23.html` and I can use `GET` to retrieve the id from the URL and use it to correctly insert the form data using SQL. Is it possible to use PHP to achieve this or is JavaScript/jQuery needed? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Modal:

```
    <div id="SelectPreFlight" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Select Tech Log</h4> </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <h5>Please select a pre-flight log to complete:</h5>
                                <div class="row">
<form method="get" action="/formpostflight.html" 
                                    <select class="form-control">
                                    <?php 
                                    include 'config.php'; 
                                    $conn=new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname); 
                                    if ($conn->connect_error) { 
                                    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error); 
                                    } 
                                    $sql = "SELECT flight_id, flight_date, duration, pilot_initial_pre, flight_nature FROM tbl_flights;"; 
                                    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("Error " . mysqli_error($conn)); ?>
                                        <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
                                            <option value = <?php echo $row['flight_id']?> > <?php echo date("d/m/Y", strtotime($row['flight_date'])) . ", " . $row['pilot_initial_pre'] . ", " . $row['flight_nature'] . ", " . date("H:i:s", strtotime($row['auth_duration'])); ?></option>
                                        <?php } ?>
                                        </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button> 
                    <a class="btn btn-info" type="submit" href="/formpostflight.html?flight_id=">Select</a>
                </div>
</form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: you dont appear to have a form on the page. try wrapping any form elements in `<form action='/page-to-direct-form-to/' method='get'></form>` Then on submitting the form you will be redirected and params placed into the querystring

Comment: Thanks, I'll edit the code now.

Comment: let me know if it works, will create an answer for you

Comment: Sorry this did not work. It still does not solve the issue of the selected flight_id being embedded into the URL.

Comment: please see my answer. You need a name attribute on the select tag

Comment: I added a name, but the form action is not doing anything. What is the 'page to redirect to' supposed to be when the id attached to it is changeable?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133029/discussion-between-atoms-and-sinesine).

Comment: You need to do it with Jquery. Get the `selected option value` and make a `url` of what you want in jquery and then append it to the `href` of your anchor tag.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap any inputs you would like to be submitted in `<form>` tags.

The `action` param is the target page you want the form to send data too.
The `method` param specifies either the `get` or `post` method to be used when sending the data.

You also havent named your `select` param. Give it a name attribute, so it will be sent with the form.

You have buttons which I guess are meant to submit the form. You will need an `id` tag on the form and a `form` tag with the same name on the button:

```
<form action='/page-to-direct-to/' method='get' id='form1'>
     <button type="submit" form="form1" value="Submit">Submit</button> 
</form>
```

I would use an input instead:

```
<form action='/page-to-direct-to/' method='get'>

    <!-- other inputs -->

       <select class="form-control" name='flight_id'>
           <?php // php code ?>
       </select>

    <input type='submit' value='Submit' name='Submit' />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as, I have understood of what you want. I have done a simple code snippet. You can try and let know me. Here I have just picked up a value from `Dropdown` and assign it to the anchor tag which is in your case `Select` name. And now when you see the anchor tag it will have a generated url.

With each change in dropdown the url of your anchor tag will become something like.

```
/formpostflight.html?flight_id=1
/formpostflight.html?flight_id=2 //and so on...
```

```js
const change_url = () => {
  var id = $('#record option:selected').val();
  var submit = $("#submit_url");
  if (id != '')
    submit.attr('href', "/formpostflight.html?flight_id=" + id);
  else
    submit.attr('href', "#");
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="record" onchange="change_url()">
  <option value="">Choose</option>
  <option value="1">First</option>
  <option value="2">Second</option>
  <option value="3">Third</option>
  <option value="4">Fourth</option>
</select>

<a href="#" id='submit_url'>Select</a>
```